# Changing tag name in a xml to a value in another xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

Please look at my source XML, i want to convert that to destination XML using XSLT. But i was not successful, please help in providing the valid XSLT.

Source XML :

```
<Details>
   <ID>1</ID>
   <CUDF1>XYZ</CUDF1>
   <Type>B</Type>
   <Style>S</Style>
   <BOM>B1</BOM>
</Details>
```

Destination XML :

```
<Table>
  <Row>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>CUDF1</Name>
    <Value>XYZ</Value>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Type</Name>
    <Value>B</Value>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>Style</Name>
    <Value>S</Value>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Name>BOM</Name>
    <Value>B1</Value>
  </Row>
</Table>
```

Here is my XSLT :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
      <Table>
       <xsl:for-each select="child::node()"> 
        <xsl:element name="Row">
          <xsl:copy-of select="ID"></xsl:copy-of>
          <xsl:element name="Name">
            <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
          </xsl:element>
          <xsl:element name="Value">
            <xsl:value-of select="/@Name"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When i link this XSLT to sample XML i am getting nothing in my browser(IE). What am i doing wrong ? Is there a way to debug this in IE or any other browser ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way SO works.  We won't "provide the valid XSLT" for you if you've made no effort to solve the problem.  SO is not a code-writing service.  Show us what you've tried and explain what doesn't work and then we can help you.

Comment: HI Jim, thanks for your inputs. I didn't know that. I have updated my question. Please take a look and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your stylesheet - other than being unnecessarily verbose - is **context**. Your template matches `"/"` so you are in the context of the root node. In this context:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="ID"></xsl:copy-of>
```

returns nothing, because ID is not a child of the root node. You need to use:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="Details/ID"></xsl:copy-of>
```

and so on for the other nodes you wish to copy.

---

### Edit:

> So i don't want to bind my XSLT with the tag names under Details
>   except for ID

That's okay, but you still need to respect your context, so instead of:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="child::node()">
```

you should have:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="Details/*">
```

and then:

```
<xsl:element name="Row">
    <xsl:copy-of select="../ID"></xsl:copy-of>
    <xsl:element name="Name">
        <xsl:value-of select="name(.)"/>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:element name="Value">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:element>
```

or, if you want to keep it shorter, just:

```
<Row>
    <xsl:copy-of select="../ID"/>
    <Name><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/></Name>
    <Value><xsl:value-of select="."/></Value>
</Row>
```

Comment: Okay for ID, But under <Details> root there can be few more tags. So i don't want to bind my XSLT with the tag names under Details except for ID

Comment: Thanks for the update, this works. But I wanted to have ID tag on each of the Row tags. But it's appearing only ones.

Comment: I have added it as one more element inside the row it started working.

Comment: Hi Michael - I want to improve this to filter out some of the tags. So i am creating a variable like this. 
<xsl:variable name="target" select="name(.)" ></xsl:variable>
and using an if conditions to filter the tags.
<xsl:if test="((not(contains($target,$filter1))) or (not(contains($target,$filter2))) or (not(contains($target,$filter3))) )">
filter1, 2 and 3 respectively are the hard coded values to filter the tags.